# Как написать регулярное выражение на python?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка типа `"c:\DFT17\BP-550.01.04.159 Proushina_[ЧИСЛО][БУКВЫ]_st3_8sht.DFT"`.

Вместо `[ЧИСЛО]` может стоять любое число(Например: 17.5 16,7 19)

Вместо `[БУКВЫ]` может стоять "mm" или "мм"

Между `[ЧИСЛО]` и `[БУКВЫ]` может стоять любое колво пробелов

Нужно достать `[ЧИСЛО][БУКВЫ]`

Значит если дана строка

```
"c:\DFT17\BP-550.01.04.159 Proushina_6.7 мм_st3_8sht.DFT",
```

то нужно достать "6.7мм"

Самая главная проблема у меня с "мм".

Comment: число и буквы __всегда__ обрамлены символом подчеркивания?

Comment: Нет, не всегда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не мудрить, то вот так: https://ideone.com/U9bwem

```
import re

s = 'c:\DFT17\BP-550.01.04.159 Proushina_6.7 мм_st3_8sht.DFT'
print(re.findall('(\d+[.,]\d*)\s*(mm|мм)', s))
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [36]: pat = r'([-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+)\s*([mм]{2})'

In [37]: s1
Out[37]: 'c:\\DFT17\\BP-550.01.04.159 Proushina_6.7 мм_st3_8sht.DFT'

In [38]: re.findall(pat, s1)
Out[38]: [('6.7', 'мм')]

In [39]: s2
Out[39]: 'c:\\DFT17\\BP-550.01.04.159 Proushina_67 мм_st3_8sht.DFT'

In [40]: re.findall(pat, s2)
Out[40]: [('67', 'мм')]

In [41]: s3
Out[41]: 'c:\\DFT17\\BP-550.01.04.159 Proushina_1,23 мм_st3_8sht.DFT'

In [42]: re.findall(pat, s3)
Out[42]: [('1,23', 'мм')]

In [43]: s4 = "c:\DFT17\BP-550.01.04.159 Proushina_567 mm_st3_8sht.DFT"

In [44]: re.findall(pat, s4)
Out[44]: [('567', 'mm')]

In [46]: s5 = "c:\DFT17\BP120.01.180.004_Knica_19мм_St3_10sht.DFT"

In [47]: re.findall(pat, s5)
Out[47]: [('19', 'мм')]
```

PS я от себя добавил парсинг необязательного знака (`+` или `-`) перед числом

---

**UPDATE:**

> Что поменять, если вместо мм и mm может шт или sht?

```
In [54]: s6 = "c:\DFT17\BP120.01.180.004_Knica_8.99 мм_St3_10sht.DFT"

In [55]: pat = r'([-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+)\s*([mм]{2}|шт|sht)'

In [56]: re.findall(pat, s6)
Out[56]: [('8.99', 'мм'), ('10', 'sht')]
```

Comment: Всё хорошо, но не находит с "мм".

Comment: @ДимаСурок, если трех примеров из моего ответа не достаточно, то попробуйте привести в вопросе дополнительные примеры строк с которыми возникают трудности ;-)

Comment: Всё понятно, но в строке c:\DFT17\BP120.01.180.004_Knica_19мм_St3_10sht.DFT не находит 19мм

Comment: @ДимаСурок, смотрите обновленный ответ - у меня все работает

Comment: Может с кодировкой, что-то не то может быть?

Comment: @ДимаСурок, врядли вам здесь смогут помочь не имея __воспроизводимого__ примера

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ладно, это я уже сам исправлю. Ещё один вопрос. Что поменять, если вместо мм и mm может шт или sht

Answer (score -1):

если будут подчеркивании  *[ЧИСЛО][БУКВЫ]* посмотрите на это:

```
pat = r'_(.*[m,м,т,t])_'
```

для любой комбинации m,м,т,t -  [m,м,т,t] - mm - мм - шт - sht

Comment: Что-то сомнительно. И что в символьной группе делают запятые?

Comment: Запятые поставил для лучшего понимания процесса. Оператор  [..]  соответствует одному из символов. Вы провертеть пожалуйста.

Comment: Во втором комментарии автор говорит, что подчёркивания по краям не всегда. К тому же, если там будут ещё подчёркивания, в совпадение попадёт куча лишнего. Ну и запятые же тоже смогут сматчиться. Откуда взялось желание находить что-то кроме mm и мм я тоже не понял - вроде в вопросе про это нет.

Comment: А, нашёл про шт/sht.

Comment: А минус был не мой... Ну или за нами обоими минусатор пришёл :(

Comment: так Вы поставили под сомнение запятые. А народ  не знает шаблоны. Невежество побеждает зло.

Comment: Запятые там не к месту. Если кто-то чего-то не знает, он должен это узнать. И не надо специально под незнание делать неправильно.